# Get visitor's Optimizely A/B test and variation

Tags: javascript, api, optimizely

When I run an experiment on my website, I want to be able to find out which test and variation the current visitor sees. I can't find how to do this from the [Optimizely Javascript API](https://www.optimizely.com/docs/api).

Comment: Have you checked the section of the API documentation that mentions referencing the data object? You can see the variations you are currently cookied to with optimizely.variationIdsMap and optimizely.variationNamesMap

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get the ID of the first running experiment (assuming you have one), and then the variation index (e.g., 0, 1, 2), name, and ID:

```
var experimentID = window['optimizely'].data.state.activeExperiments[0];
var variationIndex = window['optimizely'].data.state.variationMap[experimentID];
var variationName = window['optimizely'].data.state.variationNamesMap[experimentID];
var variationID = window['optimizely'].data.state.variationIdsMap[experimentID];
```

Comment: Is there any possible way to get the **actual** experiment ID?

**Actual** meaning the experiment that contains the the code that is trying to access it.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Kevin Borders' answer. It's possible that you are running more than one experiment on a page. I've included a code snippet below, demonstrating how to return an array of active variation IDs:

```
// Return a list of active Optimizely variation IDs
function activeVariations(){

  // Multiple variations may currently be active
  var activeVariations = [];

  // Get state settings from optimizely object
  var state = window['optimizely'].data.state;

  // For each of the active experiments:
  for (var i = state.activeExperiments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    // Current experiment ID
    var experimentID = state.activeExperiments[i];

    // Current corresponding variation ID
    var variationID = state.variationIdsMap[experimentID];

    // If we have an active variation, add it to our array
    if (variationID) { activeVariations.push(variationID[0]); }
  }

  // List of active variations
  return activeVariations;
}
```

Comment: Is there any possible way to get the **actual** experiment ID?

**Actual** meaning the experiment that contains the the code that is trying to access it.

Comment: @SilverRingvee Can you expand on your question? Perhaps provide an example. I'd like to help, but I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to get?

Comment: For example if I try to access experiment ID in experiment Javascript. So the same function would return different ID for each each experiment that contains that function. Same should work in Variation JS as well..

I hope I explained myself better now and you can help me.

Comment: The optimizely object contains an "active experiments" key: 

``optimizely.activeExperiments`` - this will return a list of all experiments currently running on the page for that visitor. Is this what you're looking for?

Source: https://help.optimizely.com/hc/en-us/articles/205670207-The-console-data-object-and-Optimizely-log

Comment: No this is not what I am looking for. I need the exact (ONLY ONE) experiment ID. Something that I can write either in Experiment JS or Variation JS and would return the value for THAT experiment ID.