# How can I get the active experiment/variant name in optimizely?

Tags: angularjs, optimizely

I try to integrate Optimizely with AngularJS and I want to show different templates based on what variation is running. I would add a constant function to the Angular app, that would check if a variant/variants are active.

sth like

```
function isVariant(variantNames) {
   return true; // if any of the variants are active.
}
```

I could not find in the Optimizely documentation on how to get this data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimizely: Get the variation of the current visitor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326157/optimizely-get-the-variation-of-the-current-visitor)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326157/optimizely-get-the-variation-of-the-current-visitor?rq=1 and the question is basically answered there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check which experiments are active with

```
optimizely.activeExperiments
```

To get the variation in which you are bucketed you can use

```
optimizely.variationNamesMap
```

Chris